# How to use dependency injection in go

Tags: go, dependency-injection

I am learning dependency injection and want to use it in a gRPC project but I am not sure how to do it.
I have this gRPC service

```
service UserService {
    rpc GetUser(GetUserRequest) returns (User);
}

message GetUserRequest {
    oneof prop {
        string id = 1;
        string email = 2;
        string phoneNumber = 3;
    } 
}

message User {
    string firstName = 1;
    string lastName = 2;                                            
    ...
}
```

Then in the main function define the GetUser and initialise the server

main.go

```
package main

import (
    pb "proto/user/go"
    "context"
    "net"
    "fmt"
)

type Server struct {
    pb.UserServiceServer
}

func (s *Server) GetUser(ctx context.Context, req *pb.GetUserRequest) (*pb.User, error) {
    var user pb.User
    var err error
    switch req.Prop.(type) {
    case *pb.GetUserRequest_Email:
        user, err = GetUserByEmail(req.GetEmail())
    case *pb.GetUserRequest_Id:
        user, err = GetUserById(req.GetId())
    case *pb.GetUserRequest_PhoneNumber:
        user, err = GetUserByPhoneNumber(req.GetPhoneNumber())
    }
    return &user, err
}

func main() {
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":50051")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to listen for incoming requests")
    }
    s := grpc.NewServer()
    cs := Server{}
    pb.RegisterUserServiceServer(s, cs)
    err = s.Serve(lis)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to start server: ", err)
    }
}
```

The `GetUserByEmail`, `GetUserById` and `GetUserByPhoneNumber` are located in another package

user/get_user.go

```
func GetUserById(id string) (pb.User, error) {
    // call the database to get the user
}
```

So my question is in order to make testing  `GetUserByEmail`, `GetUserById` and `GetUserByPhoneNumber` easier I have to dependency inject the database connection and I am not sure what the best way to do it is.
My first thought was to add a field to the Server struct called `db` and then in `GetUser` pass it to the functions so it would look like this.

```
type Server struct {
    pb.UserServiceServer
    db *dynamodb.Client
}

func (s *Server) GetUser(ctx context.Context, req *pb.GetUserRequest) (*pb.User, error) {
    var user pb.User
    var err error
    switch req.Prop.(type) {
    case *pb.GetUserRequest_Email:
        user, err = GetUserByEmail(req.GetEmail(), s.db)
    case *pb.GetUserRequest_Id:
        user, err = GetUserById(req.GetId(), s.db)
    case *pb.GetUserRequest_PhoneNumber:
        user, err = GetUserByPhoneNumber(req.GetPhoneNumber(), s.db)
    }
    return &user, err
}
```

I feel like its not good practice to pass the db using parameters but I could be wrong.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

At it's simplest, dependency injection is just adding a parameter for something that is independent. It separates code that uses something from code that creates/destroys something. The pattern is roughly "create stuff, use it, dispose of stuff".

The "create" part can be multiple steps. It can be done in layers (each handling a "create" and "dispose" of one thing), or it can create objects from multiple parts (and combine those in turn), but I don't think there's a "best" way in all cases.

Generally the "dispose" part is a mirror of the "create" part to be consistent (minus anything pre-existing, or that you want to keep afterward). But the details of what or how to pass things depends on how you want to structure your code in general.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using Kratos, and I think it demonstrate dependency injection perfectly. You may explore its [layout](https://go-kratos.dev/en/docs/intro/layout/) and [injection](https://go-kratos.dev/en/docs/guide/wire) for details.

Briefly speaking:

1. Abstract db access, i.e. interface instead of struct, just like what you did in `pb.RegisterUserServiceServer(s, cs)`, you should have database interface that declares the methods in need.

> ```
> type dbInterface interface{
>    GetUser(ctx context.Context, id int64) (*pb.User, error)
>    ...
> }
> ```

2. Implement a struct for the interface

> ```
> type dbStruct struct {
>     // Your real client here
>     ...
> }
>
> // assert implementation
> var _ dbInterface = (*dbStruct)(nil)
>
> // implementations
> func  (s *dbStruct) GetUser(ctx context.Context, id int64) (*pb.User, error) {
>     ...
> }
> ```

3. *Providers* for [Wire](https://go.dev/blog/wire) to inject.

> ```
> func NewDB(...) (*dbStruct, error)
> func NewServer(...) (*Server, error)
> ```

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing wrong with passing the dependency of the database connector (by passing by link). And yet, I would recommend that you create a structure in your separate package where you would describe the database client interface, and hang the necessary methods on this structure.[ex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiWha.jpg)